# Ubuntu 19.10: Retries password after re-installing bcmwl-kernel-source

Tags: networking, kernel, connection, iwlwifi

There is an Ubuntu 19.10 with all recent updated up to date.

### Problem

Wifi is unable to connect to a secured point. The password is correct, but the popup window would re-ask for the password again and again.

### When problem started

The wifi actually worked fine. But then tried to run: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` (according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes#Known_issues).

After that - unable to connect.

### Details

For some reason Wireless is shown as `Ethernet interface`.

```
lshw -class network
[sudo] password for obiol: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 59
       serial: 7c:b0:c2:14:71:ac
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-26-generic firmware=29.62a39462.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:140 memory:df300000-df301fff
```

Errors:

```
an 17 16:49:12 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Jan 17 16:49:28 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: nl80211: kernel reports: NLA_F_NESTED is missing
Jan 17 16:49:28 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Jan 17 16:49:37 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: nl80211: kernel reports: NLA_F_NESTED is missing
Jan 17 16:49:37 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Jan 17 16:49:52 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Jan 17 16:53:58 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: nl80211: kernel reports: NLA_F_NESTED is missing
Jan 17 16:53:58 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Jan 17 16:58:51 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: nl80211: kernel reports: NLA_F_NESTED is missing
Jan 17 16:58:51 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Jan 17 16:58:55 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: nl80211: kernel reports: NLA_F_NESTED is missing
Jan 17 16:58:55 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Jan 17 16:59:00 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: nl80211: kernel reports: NLA_F_NESTED is missing
Jan 17 16:59:00 n552vw wpa_supplicant[1164]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
```

---

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: `bcmwl-kernel-source` is a driver for certain Broadcom wireless devices. You clearly have an Intel. I recommend that you: `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be bugs related to Wifi modul and the recent kernel. Here is one of the treads related to it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/backport-iwlwifi-dkms/+bug/1849891.

### Solution

In my case, simply removing the iwlwifi backport. `sudo apt-get remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms` and rebooting resolved the issue. Able to connect to Wifi again.